# core/session value not available on custom module page

Tags: magento-1.7, module, session

I'm using core/session for storing values, I'm use the following code to store the value:

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyWishlist( $newmywishlist );`

On category and product pages but also on cms pages I can read the value by using:

`$mywishlist = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyWishlist();`

But on pages from my custom modules, not a cms page, I can't get the value.

When I debug core/session I also noticed that the session_id is different on the custom module page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your custom module working in the admin or frontend area? There are different session scopes at hand in this case that might cause your problem.

Have a look at Alan Storm's post on cross area sessions: http://alanstorm.com/magento_cross_area_sessions

Comment: Both sessions are frontend sessions. I took al look at the cross area session. You never know when you don't try ;) . I have installed the module and trying to access the sessions with the code from the readme but I get an error  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSessionData() on a non-object in

Comment: It's working :) My FTP client didn't upload the complete directory with all files. When I use `$frontend = Mage::getModel('pulsestorm_crossareasession/manager')->getSessionData('frontend'); ` I also see the MyWishlist value on custom module pages. Note that both pages are on the frontend. Thanx :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's working now.